# Why/How does the change in weather trigger arthritic pain and migraines?

Tags: arthritis, migraine, triggers, contributing-factors, weather

There is that old wives' tales: "I can feel it (storm coming) in my bones." But I actually find, at least for me, that this is somewhat accurate. What is it about the change in the weather that causes my joints to stiffen-up and cause aches and pains and trigger migraines?

What unseen environmental factors are at play, which are wrecking havoc on my body, whenever the weather changes? How & Why?